# Adding to a store from JTextfields from JPanel/JFrame

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, swing, arraylist

I have developed a store class, which holds information from an employee and a person class.

In my controller class, I have added one employee to the store:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee("Dave", 'M', new Date(01,1,80), "01", new Date(02,2,2002));
```

What I am trying to do is add a more employees to the store using information inputted from a keyboard in a JPanel/JFrame. I have developed the JTextfields and JButtons.

I have got as far as defining the buttons and fields:

```
JButton enterButton;
JTextField name;
JTextField gender;
JTextField dob;
JTextField id;
JTextField startDate;
```

I have constructed each of them and they all appear on the JPanel.  I know I need to add the actionListener and have done so as follows:

```
myEventHandler h = new myEventHandler();

enterButton.addActionListener(h);
name.addActionListener(h);
gender.addActionListener(h);
dob.addActionListener(h);
id.addActionListener(h);
startDate.addActionListener(h);
```

I then created a class:

```
private class myEventHandler implements ActionListener {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
```

But it is at this point my code breaks down:

```
if(e.getSource()==enterButton) {
```

How do I make it so that clicking this enterButton takes the information entered into the five JTextfields and adds this as a new Employee to my store class?

I have researched into this and I am resorting to putting this on here as a last resort. Some pointers to get me going again would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already declared the `JTextField`s, you just need to use them correctly in order to create a new `Employee`. The more difficult part at that is to correctly convert a string into a `Date`. I would also recommend using a `JFormattedTextField` for the textfields with dates.

I used [`substring()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm) and `Integer.parseInt()` to convert a string into a Date. Note that you have to substract 1 from the month since it starts counting at 0 (so 0 = January). Also you have to substract 1900 from the year, since it  is "*year minus 1900*" ([Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html))

Here's an example, the `Employee`-class just prints out the arguments to a `JTextArea` (so we know it's correct).

**Output:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Example {

    JButton enterButton;
    JTextField name;
    JTextField gender;
    JFormattedTextField dob;
    JTextField id;
    JFormattedTextField startDate;
    JTextArea outputArea;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });

    }

    public Example() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        MyEventHandler eventHandler = new MyEventHandler();

        enterButton = new JButton("Apply");
        enterButton.addActionListener(eventHandler);

        name = new JTextField(10);
        name.addActionListener(eventHandler);

        gender = new JTextField(10);
        gender.addActionListener(eventHandler);

        dob = new JFormattedTextField(df);
        dob.setColumns(10);
        dob.addActionListener(eventHandler);

        id = new JTextField(10);
        id.addActionListener(eventHandler);

        startDate = new JFormattedTextField(df);
        startDate.setColumns(10);
        startDate.addActionListener(eventHandler);

        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel.add(name);
        inputPanel.add(gender);
        inputPanel.add(dob);
        inputPanel.add(id);
        inputPanel.add(startDate);
        inputPanel.add(enterButton);

        outputArea = new JTextArea();

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(outputArea));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(frame.getWidth(), 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class MyEventHandler implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Employee(name.getText(), gender.getText(), getDateOf(dob), id.getText(), getDateOf(startDate));
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private Date getDateOf(JFormattedTextField field) {
        int year = Integer.parseInt(field.getText().substring(6, 10)) - 1900;
        int month = Integer.parseInt(field.getText().substring(3, 5)) - 1;
        int date = Integer.parseInt(field.getText().substring(0, 2));
        return new Date(year, month, date);
    }

    public class Employee {

        public Employee(String name, String gender, Date dob, String id, Date startDate) {
            outputArea.append((name + "\n" + gender + "\n" + dob + "\n" + id + "\n" + startDate + "\n"));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You don't want to add the listener to anything other than the enterButton. Otherwise this code will add a new Employee whenever the user finishes entering something in any of the text fields, before anything is entered in any of the other fields.

Comment: @FredK I don't fully understand. As you can see in my gif/code, it doesn't. It only adds a new `Employee` when you press `Enter` in one of the textfields (which is what the OP wants), not when you switch textfields.

Comment: @LuxxMiner I think this is working but my issue is then how to add this to my arrayList. `new Employee(name.getText(), gender.getText(), getDateOf(dob), id.getText(), getDateOf(startDate));` seems to work but how do I then add this to my ArrayList in my 'Contoller' class?

Comment: @LuxxMiner Having said that, I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I try to run it. I'm completely lost now.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're using the wrong Listener. You must use `KeyListener` to achieve what you want.
2. Use Java Beans naming conventions: Every class must have it's name started with an Upper Case letter.

Your code will look like this:

```
public class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {

    }

   @Override
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
       if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
          // do your stuff here
       }
   }
}
```

And add to one of your, or each of your text fields, this listener.

Comment: An `ActionListener` will automatically also register the enter key event, there's no need for a `KeyListener`. Also the question seems to be how to take all the information of the textfields and making a new `Employee` out of it.

Comment: Well, that, sir, I didn't know. But, now that you did point it out, it would be nice if you answer the question.
Btw, thanks =)